# How to change file name without changing extension of file in Python?

Tags: python, file-extension, file-rename

As you know extension of files not important in *nix systems but we still use it for ease of use. However in Windows, it is important.

I have a server program(python) in a linux machine which sends files to clients. Some files have extension, some files not have extension and some of them have one or multiple dots(.) in file name.

In windows machines(Extensions are hided or not) how to change file name without changing extension.?

For example:

The files send from my Linux Server:

```
      abc.txt (txt files)
      def.doc (doc files)
      qwe.qwe.qwe (text files not have extension)
```

The desired output on Windows Machine1 (not hide extension):

```
     abc_Monday.txt (txt files)
     def_Monday.doc (doc files)
     qwe.qwe.qwe_Monday (text files not have extension)
```

The desired output on Windows Machine2 (hide extensions):

```
     abc_Monday (txt files but extension is not seen)
     def_Monday (doc files but extension is not seen)
     qwe.qwe.qwe_Monday (text files not have extension)
```

And also so many file extension exist. Because of that I don't want to use a black list to determine file extensions. How do I differentiate the file has extension or not and how to rename it without changing its extension in python client side?

Comment: `qwe` is the extension.. I don't understand how you're not going to hide that

Comment: I don't want to hide qwe. It is not a extension, I just made it up. Another example of file file not have extension send from my Linux machine.
"myfile_02.02.2015"
This file contains dot but have no extension. Before renaming my files how to differentiate automatically a file has extention or not ?

Comment: `.qwe` could be (or probably is) a valid file extension. You should make a list of "valid" (according to you) file extensions.

Comment: qwe is just an example. We can change that ".sjdvsgdsd" Thanks for suggesting a list. I just wonder any other options exist or not in python to understand extension of file.

Comment: .sjdvsgdsd is just as valid. You could find file extensions currently known to your system and use them as a whitelist, but I don't think that will really help.

Comment: anything after the last dot **is** an extension. it doesn't matter what you think about it...

Answer (score 0):

Technically, extensions don't matter anywhere. They are just filenames with suffixes for convenience. Even on Windows, you can always link certain extensions to certain applications which will have to be a one time consideration in any case. So, probably you are wasting time on the wrong thing unless you have certain mapping from `MIME-types` to particular extension on Windows already planned.